# preg_match_all() php doesn't output good occurrences

Tags: php, regex

I don't understand why my really simple regex react like that, I've never been in this situation before:

```
$string = "you are the best pirate of the world";
if (preg_match_all("/pira|pirate|wor|world/", $string, $output)) {
    // $output => array(array('pira', 'wor'));
}
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/meS : on this link you will have a bette view.
So here, the output is "pira" and "wor" whereas I want to have "pirate" and "world". I must have missed something.

How to make it match the exact word ?

Comment: The first alternative that matches makes the regex engine stop checking the other alternatives on the right. Use `"/wor(?:ld)?|pira(?:te)?/"`. Or, if you are matching whole words, use word boundaries - `"/\b(?:pira|pirate|wor|world)\b/"`

Comment: Thank you I've done it but I don't undestand why it reacts like that, why stop and why doesn't take the exact occurence.

Comment: Read [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Comment: Yes but we can not say that this is a valid match when it output the occurence that contain the half of the letters. this is common sense and logic.

Comment: First match wins.  That's how it works.  What's being output doesn't "contain the half of the letters", it contains exactly what you're telling it to match.